# i tcreated an orl module in fuelphp and itt keeps throwing me Fatal Error! ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: when i try using it

Tags: php, mysql, orm, xampp, fuelphp

the module:

```
class Model_Categories extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_connection = 'production';
    protected static $_table_name = 'categories';
    protected static $_primary_key = array('id');
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'name' => array(
            'data_type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'category name',
            'form' => array(
                'type' =>'text'
            ),
        ),
        'image_location' => array(
            'data_type' =>'text',
            'label' =>'category image locartion',
            'form' =>array(
                'type'=>'text'
            ),
        ),
        'timestamp' => array(
            'data_type' =>'timestamp',
            'label' =>'category image location',
            'form' =>array(
                'type'=>'timestamp'
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

and when i try to run

```
            $model = Model_Categories::find('all');
```

it shows me
Fatal Error!
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException: Return type of Orm\Model::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\packages\orm\classes\model.php:2536 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\bootstrap.php(112): Fuel\Core\Errorhandler::error_handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 2536) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\packages\orm\classes\model.php(25): {closure}(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 2536) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\classes\autoloader.php(365): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\classes\autoloader.php(236): Fuel\Core\Autoloader::init_class('Orm\Model', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\app\classes\model\categories.php(2): Fuel\Core\Autoloader::load('Orm\Model') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\classes\autoloader.php(365): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\classes\autoloader.php(283): Fuel\Core\Autoloader::init_class('Model_Categorie...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\app\classes\controller\qoute.php(16): Fuel\Core\Autoloader::load('Model_Categorie...') #8 [internal function]: Controller_Qoute->action_categories() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\fuel\core\classes\request.php(483): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Controller_Qoute), Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\public\index.php(133): Fuel\Core\Request->execute() #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\qouter\public\index.php(172): {closure}() #12 {main}

PKGPATH//orm/classes/model.php @ line 25

anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP 8.1 and a version of FuelPHP that is not compatible.

Switch to the 1.9/dev branch, most of the PHP 8.1. deprecation issues have been solved there.